# Lua - Error running script via Crontab with os.execute command - Exit code = 32512

Tags: shell, lua, cron

I have a Lua script that I’m trying to run via crontab - see request/schedule below.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 8 * * * /usr/bin/lua /home/pi/shared/TS_cabin_graph_watts_12h.lua >/home/pi/shared/watts.log 2>&1
1 8 * * * /usr/bin/lua /home/pi/shared/TS_cabin_graph_temp_12h.lua >/home/pi/shared/temp.log 2>&1
```

The whole script does a lot of different things, but here’s the specific os.execute graph request below.

```
print("Start : graph command")
local x = os.execute('graph /home/pi/shared/feed12hr.csv -y 9,10 --ylabel Temp --title CabinTemp --figsize 1600x1000 --output /home/pi/shared/cabingraph12hr.png') 
print(x)
print("End : graph command")
```

When I run it manually at the command line myself, it works fine - see output below.

```
Start : graph command
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_converter.py:129: FutureWarning: Using an implicitly registered datetime converter for a matplotlib plotting method. The converter was registered by pandas on import. Future versions of pandas will require you to explicitly register matplotlib converters.

To register the converters:
        >>> from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
        >>> register_matplotlib_converters()
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)
0
End : graph command
```

but when I check the logs after it runs via a cronjob, it fails and reports the following

```
Part 4
Start : graph command
32512
End : graph command
```

Any idea of the cause and required fix ?

Answer (score 0):

The error means "file not found".
This is because cron runs your tasks with very minimalistic `$PATH`, so you must specify full path to `graph` executable when invoking `os.execute()`.

Comment: Hi, I added the full path /usr/local/bin/graph, checked it works manually first m and then I allowed it to run via cron, which now gives me a ‘256’ error/exit code ? Any ideas on how to address that ?

Answer (score 0):

In Lua 5.1, `os.execute` returns whatever the C `system` function returns. In Linux, using the decoding macros explained in [`man 3 system`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), the return value `32512` decodes to `WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 127`. In newer versions of Lua, you wouldn't have to do this decoding manually, as it would instead decode it for you and return `nil, 'exit', 127`. The reason for that exit code is that `system` runs a shell, and when the shell returns 127, it's because it can't find the file you told it to execute. The most likely reason that you'd have that problem in a cron job but not interactively is that cron jobs use a different set of environment variables, and the `PATH` environment variable in cron doesn't contain the location of `graph`. Do `which graph` interactively to see where it is, then update your script to use that full path.

Comment: Hi @Joseph - thanks I did as suggested and put the full path in, but I now get a 256 error/exit code..  FYI - I also tried the script with io.popen, but that gave me a ‘graph’ error  message, which I’ll have to take up with the graph-cli app owner.